# Asp .Net 4 and Literal output

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Hello I found next strange as for me behavior of Literal in Asp MVC out put and I don't know how to fix it.
I have next part of html code on aspx page

```
    ...
<p class="description">
        <asp:Literal ID="lblDescription" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
    </p>
   ...
```

On page load event I try to show user text:

```
lblDescription.Text = stringVar;
```

string var can contain other html tag like **p, div, etc**

But when my page loaded I see all html that should be inside

was created under this element.

some text

Does any one know why ?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblDescription" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
```

[MSDN: Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx)

Comment: thanks. but result is bad it doesn't help just Encode mode working but it display html like text